# Caching Property Getter/Setter in .NET Compact Framework

Tags: generics, orm, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am working on an ORM for a Windows CE device. I need to cache getter/setter methods of properties as delegates and call them when needed for best perfromance.

Lets say I have 2 entities defined like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int HP { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to hold 2 delegates for each property of each entities. So I create a AccessorDelegates class to hold 2 delegates for each property:

```
 public class AccessorDelegates<T>
{
    public Action<T, object> Setter;
    public Func<T, object> Getter;

    public AccessorDelegates(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        MethodInfo getMethod = propertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
        MethodInfo setMethod = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod();

        Setter = BuildSetter(setMethod, propertyInfo); // These methods are helpers
        Getter = BuildGetter(getMethod, propertyInfo); // Can be ignored
    }
}
```

Now I want to add each AccessorDelegates for a specific entity type into a list. So I defined a class:

```
public class EntityProperties<T>
{
    public List<AccessorDelegates<T>> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

I need to hold these EntityProperties for each entity type, in my example Car and Driver. I created a `Dictionary<string, EntityProperties<T>>` string representing entity name just for simplicity for now:

```
public class Repo<T>
{
    public Dictionary<string, EntityProperties<T>> EntityPropDict { get; set; }
}
```

This is where I cannot find a solution to my problem. I want to hold `EntityProperties` for each entity type but I have to give `Repo<T>` class a type parameter to be able to create the dictionary (because `EntityProperties<T>` requires a **type parameter**).

**I need to be able to create it without a type parameter as `Repo` only.** How can I define a `Dictionary<string, EntityProperties<T>>` without giving my Repo class a type parameter?

Comment: You lost me here **public class EntityProperties<T>** I don't understand what the Type in the class represents and how it relates to AccessorDelegates<T>. It would seem for AccessorDelegates<T> the T type represents the Type of the property. But, how are you assuming An EntityProperties<T> has Properties that all have the same Type?

Comment: That type T represents one of the entities, either Car or Driver. AccessorDelegates<Car> would need type Car to know the type of the object to call a property on. For example int speed = myCar.Speed, myCar would be the objeect to call Speed property on. So I would need a **Func<Car, int>** method to cache the getter method, **here T is being Car**.

Comment: Don't repositories typically wrap a single entity type?  A `Repo<Car>` would expose `Car` entities and have an `EntityProperties<Car>` instance which in turn holds a list of `AccessorDelegates<Car>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to a solution, a little smart code but works fine.

I added an interface to be implemented by AccessorDelegates:

```
public interface IAccessorDelegates
{
    void Init(PropertyInfo propertyInfo);
}
```

I changed my PropertyMetadata to contain an IAccessorDelegate instead of AccessorDelegate:

```
public class PropertyMetadata
{
    public PropMapAttribute Attribute { get; set; }
    public PropertyInfo PropertyInfo { get; set; }
    public IAccessorDelegates AccessorDelegates { get; set; }

    public PropertyMetadata()
    {

    }

    public PropertyMetadata(PropMapAttribute attribute, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, IAccessorDelegates delegates)
    {
        Attribute = attribute;
        PropertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        AccessorDelegates = delegates;
    }

    public AccessorDelegates<T> GetAccesssorDelegates<T>()
    {
        return (AccessorDelegates<T>)AccessorDelegates;
    }
}
```

Now, I can create and initialize an AccessorDelegate this way:

```
 Type accesssorType = typeof(AccessorDelegates<>);
 Type genericAccessorType = accesssorType.MakeGenericType(type);
 IAccessorDelegates accessor = (IAccessorDelegates)Activator.CreateInstance(genericAccessorType);
 accessor.Init(propertyInfo);
```

`PropertyMetadata.GetAccessorDelegates<T>()` method enables me to cast and get the object in actual `AccessorDelegate<T>` type.